# Pixel 5 driver/connection issues

Tags: android, android-studio, driver

I am trying to set up development on Android Studio using a Pixel 5. I am having difficulty getting my computer to properly connect to the Pixel 5 so that I can run and debug my application on it.

The Pixel 5 is already set to developer mode. I have also downloaded the Google USB driver into Android Studio. I need to install the ADB driver on my Windows 10 machine, but there appears to be no way to do this (the device manager does not display any "other drivers" and my searches on Google (of all places) for information on this matter have failed to find any.

Plugging the Pixel 5 into the computer doesn't work either. My computer charges the phone but does not actually "see" it. Going to the Device Manager doesn't help, because the Device Manager does not see the phone at all. It does not show an "Other Devices" or the "Portable Devices" referenced by the installation instructions on the Android Studio website.

As a result, I cannot use the adb tools and consequently cannot run my app on the phone.

Can someone tell me how to get this working???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple solution to this problem:

Do not use Pixel 5 for development, at least until Google resolves its problems getting it to work properly when connecting to computers, adb, Android Studio, and other applications that require a USB connection. In fact, do not use the Pixel 5 for anything other than for phone calls, connecting to *some* Bluetooth devices (it doesn't consistently communicate with all of them), and for Wifi connections.

I have returned my Pixel 5 and have replaced it with a phone that I know works properly when connected to USB devices. Until I see some people this year successfully using its USB connection, I won't even consider purchasing this phone again. Actually, I may not ever look at this phone again, considering how poor the tech support is from Google and how little accurate info there is on how to solve problems like the one I presented here.